# javascript - object value only to be worked out when needed / called upon

Tags: javascript, variables, object

for example, i have an object where the value of a key is yet to be known/computed but when i call that key for the first time it computes the value and replaces the calculation / function with the computed value. The point being that the value is only worked out when needed and then can be reused again without having to work it out again...

this is what i have so far...

```
function newobj() {
        this.test=function(){
        this.test=[1,2,3,4]//complex function in real world use
        return this.test
    }
}

a = new newobj()

a.test() //[1,2,3,4]
a.test() //not a function!
a.test //[1,2,3,4]
```

as you can see this requires parenthesis to call initially but not the second time, so this requires knowing whether it's already been called or not - not ideal

version 2

```
function newobj() {
        this.test=function(){
        var a=[1,2,3,4]
        this.test=function(){return a}
        return a
    }
}

a = new newobj()

a.test() //[1,2,3,4]
a.test() //[1,2,3,4]
```

this just somehow doesn't seem the correct way to go about this.. but maybe it is?

apologies if this is a dumb question and thanks in advance for your help

Comment: sounds like you are looking for memoization.  It is better to keep `test` a function, but just exit early if the value is already computed.  Then from the outside of the function the difference is opaque.

Comment: Why not just check if the property is `undefined` in the `test` function, and if it is, create it and return, otherwise just return. And when using the object, always call the function. EDIT:exactly as David said

Comment: @KarlReid that still requires using function invocation syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ability of a `getter` to overwrite itself to create a "lazy" property whose value is only calculated the first time it's accessed:

There's a [good example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters) at MDN.

```
get test() {
  delete this.test;
  return this.test = someExpensiveFunctionCall();
}
```

Subsequent accesses to the property don't even use the `getter` - they retrieve the value direct from the object.

In your case since you're not using the usual *getter* syntax, you'd have to modify your function thus:

```
function newobj() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'test', {
        get: function() {
            delete this.test;
            return this.test = someExpensiveFunctionCall();
        },
        configurable: true
    });
}
```

Comment: do you know if there's there a way to include the getter in the original new object function - ( newobj() in my example )? can't seem to work it out..

Comment: @wawmsey I'd use `Object.defineProperty()` - see edit

Comment: thanks, this adds the property to the object but doesn't seem to be able to delete and replace itself with the computed value. If I put console.log("bla") at the start of the get function then this is called every time - meaning it's not being deleted?

Comment: See edit - I thought my test had worked but as you found it wasn't deleting the property properly.  You have to add `configurable: true` to the property descriptor to allow the property to be removed.  You may also want to add `enumerable: true` if you want the new property to appear in the list of enumerable properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the [Module Pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/). You could do

```js
let Module = (function(){
    let test = null;
    return function(){
        if(test == null){
            console.log('initialized test');
            test = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        }
        return test;
    }
})();

let a = new Module();
console.log(a);
console.log(new Module());
```